# not getting desired results and am very stuck

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I've got an issue where it's not printing out like it should and cannot figure out what it is.

right now my code is printing out this:

> `***#`
>
> `***##`
>
> `***###`

when it should be printing out like this:

> `***#`
>
> `**##`
>
> `*###`

Here's my code as it stands now:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Box
{
  private int size;

public Box()
{




}

public Box(int count)
{
    size = count;
}

public void setSize(int count)
{
    size = count;
}

public int getSize()
{
    return size;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for(int k = size; k >0; k--)
        {
            output += "*";
        }
        for(int j = size; j >size-i; j--)
        {
            output += "#";
        }
        output += "\n"; 
    }
    
    return output;
}
}
```

and my runner class for cross-referencing:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11e
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice="";
        do{
            out.print("Enter the size of the box : ");
            int big = keyboard.nextInt();
            //out.print("Enter a letter : ");
            //String value = keyboard.next();

                //instantiate a TriangleFour object
         Box box = new Box( big);
            //call the toString method to print the triangle
            System.out.println( box );

            System.out.print("Do you want to enter more data? ");
            choice=keyboard.next();
        }while(choice.equals("Y")||choice.equals("y"));
}
}
```

My thoughts are that I'm very close to getting it but just can't figure out what.

Comment: Try using descriptive variables names. Instead of i, j, k consider row, col, etc.

Comment: I was going off of what my lab sheet associated with this lab was and that's the reason why. and I'm not sure row, col, etc would apply well in this lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        // Using a single for to make sure we don't create too many items.
        // Also note the +1. It seems that when size = 3, you want 4 chars
        // per line, so this take that extra char into account.
        for(int k = 0; k < size + 1; k++)
        {
            // Use an if to decide if we print * or #.
                // As 'i' gets bigger, we need to put less *, so
                // we subtract 'i' from the total size. This tells
                // when the midpoint has passed and we should start
                // writing #s.
            if (k <= size - i)
                output += "*";
            else
                output += "#";
        }

        output += "\n"; 
    }
```

Solution with two inner loops:

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        // Adds a number of * inversely proportional to the current
        // value of 'i'.
        for(int k = 0; k <= size - i; k++)
        {
            output += "*";
        }

        // Start adding # where we stopped the *.
        for(int j = size - i; j < size; j++)
        {
            output += "#";
        }

        output += "\n"; 
    }
```

Comment: Just in case, would there be a way to do it with 2 for loops nested within the main for-loop

Comment: Sure, just added this version to the solution. It's a little harder to see what's going on, but saves a conditional for each item.